# GeoServer not rendering GeoTIFFs after JPEG compression

Tags: geoserver, gdal, geotiff-tiff, raster-conversion, jpeg-2000

I previously asked about some problems I was having converting JP2/MrSid data to GeoTIFF for use in GeoServer. It was suggested that I needed to add overview data to the 4 GB-sized GeoTIFF -- and that helped. GeoServer then rendered and served the raster and was quite fast about it.

I've since been reading about cloud-optimized GeoTIFFs, and tried to follow the three-step process recommended [here](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/Render-images-straight-out-of-S3-with-the-vsicurl-driver):

```
gdal_translate sample.jp2 sample_deflate.tif -co tiled=yes -co BLOCKXSIZE=512 -co BLOCKYSIZE=512 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2   

cp sample_deflate.tif sample_addo.tif

gdaladdo -r average sample_addo.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config JPEG_QUALITY_OVERVIEW 85 --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL 

gdal_translate sample_addo.tif sample_compressed.tif -co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=512 -co BLOCKYSIZE=512 -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=85 -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES --config GDAL_TIFF_OVR_BLOCKSIZE 512
```

But the resulting file, after JPEG compression with photometric, would not serve at all in GeoServer. The intermediate file -- with just the added overviews -- serves fine in GeoServer, but is 6 GB in size.

Thinking the problem might be the photometric, I backed up and redid the compression with no photometric:

```
gdal_translate sample_addo.tif sample_compressed.tif -co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=512 -co BLOCKYSIZE=512 -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=85 -co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES --config GDAL_TIFF_OVR_BLOCKSIZE 512
```

It still wouldn't work. So something to do with my third step, compressing the image, is rendering it unusable by GeoServer. (It could also, I guess, be a problem with my GeoServer settings.)

Here is the gdalinfo for the third (not working) file (with photometric compression):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: sample_compressed.tif
Size is 43221, 36021
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (95.998541666740138,45.001424215510333)
Pixel Size = (0.000138888892252,-0.000138888892252)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=YCbCr JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  95.9985417,  45.0014242) ( 95d59'54.75"E, 45d 0' 5.13"N)
Lower Left  (  95.9985417,  39.9985074) ( 95d59'54.75"E, 39d59'54.63"N)
Upper Right ( 102.0014585,  45.0014242) (102d 0' 5.25"E, 45d 0' 5.13"N)
Lower Right ( 102.0014585,  39.9985074) (102d 0' 5.25"E, 39d59'54.63"N)
Center      (  99.0000001,  42.4999658) ( 99d 0' 0.00"E, 42d29'59.88"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 21611x18011, 10806x9006, 5403x4503, 2702x2252, 1351x1126, 676x563, 338x282
Band 2 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 21611x18011, 10806x9006, 5403x4503, 2702x2252, 1351x1126, 676x563, 338x282
Band 3 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 21611x18011, 10806x9006, 5403x4503, 2702x2252, 1351x1126, 676x563, 338x282
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I can get GeoServer to serve this?

Comment: I usually tile and compress the image then add the overviews. Worth a try?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we normally do it, works fast and fine for us:

https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/raster_data/processing.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem was nothing to do with what I was doing to the raster, but with GeoServer having problems with the JPEG compression itself. It's the same problem as addressed in this question:

[Problem with rendering jpeg compressed image - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.libjpegturbo.turbojpeg.TJException](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213257/problem-with-rendering-jpeg-compressed-image-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoun)