# GeoServer fails to read a JPEG compressed TIFF with alpha band

Tags: geoserver

I have been trying to publish a GeoTIFF (with JPEG compression + alpha band) but couldn't succeed. The TIFF is generated using this GDAL command:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -r bilinear -dstalpha -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=25 -co TILED=YES input.vrt output.tif
```

I am using the *dstalpha* option of `gdalwarp` in order to avoid some black seamlines on the borders of images.

Unfortunately, it seems that GeoServer doesn't handle Alpha band with JPEG compression, I get this kind of exception:

> ```
> Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type
>
> geoserver    
> |         at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1139)
> |         at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1110)
> geoserver    
> |         atit.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFJPEGDecompressor.decodeRaw(TIFFJPEGDecompressor.java:282)    
> |         at it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFDecompressor.decode(TIFFDecompressor.java:2637)    
> |         at it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.decodeTile(TIFFImageReader.java:1764)    
> |         at it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.read(TIFFImageReader.java:2065)    
> |         at com.sun.media.jai.imageioimpl.ImageReadOpImage.computeTile(ImageReadOpImage.java:697)
> ```

When doing gdalinfo on my file, everything seems fine:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: subset_nz.tif
Size is 4404, 4404
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (175.499992707622397,-37.099986337232799)
Pixel Size = (0.000022707000000,-0.000022707000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 175.4999927, -37.0999863) (175d29'59.97"E, 37d 5'59.95"S)
Lower Left  ( 175.4999927, -37.1999880) (175d29'59.97"E, 37d11'59.96"S)
Upper Right ( 175.5999943, -37.0999863) (175d35'59.98"E, 37d 5'59.95"S)
Lower Right ( 175.5999943, -37.1999880) (175d35'59.98"E, 37d11'59.96"S)
Center      ( 175.5499935, -37.1499872) (175d32'59.98"E, 37d 8'59.95"S)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

I am running GeoServer 2.16.2, is this a known issue or is there anything wrong with my files/config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, according to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213384/163480), GeoServer cannot read RGBA TIFF with JPEG compression. However, I found a solution, based on gdal_translate documentation :

> To create a JPEG-compressed TIFF with internal mask from a RGBA dataset
>
> `gdal_translate rgba.tif withmask.tif -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -mask 4 -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR --config GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK YES`

Geoserver can read the TIFF resulting from this command and the behavior is exactly the one I was expecting with the initial RGBA TIFF.