# GeoServer ImageMosaic doesn't handle internal mask for JPEG compression GeoTIFF

Tags: geoserver

Following my question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/361277/163480), I am publishing some GeoTIFF with JPEG compression and internal mask.

It works as expected when I publish the image under a GeoTIFF store but doesn't when I publish from an ImageMosaic store. 
Here are the previews rendered by GeoServer: 
[image: imagemosaic vs geotiff store]

My first thought was that the ImageMosaic wasn't using the same driver as the GeoTIFF store publishing. So I tried to change the **SuggestedSPI** in the ImageMosaic *.properties* file from `it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi` to  `it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.geotiff.GeoTiffImageReaderSpi`

But GeoServer fails to create such store with a suggestedSPI that is not the default `TIFFImageReaderSpi`.

I didn't find much documentation on changing the suggestedSPI, does anyone know why the `GeoTiffImageReaderSpi` doesn't work? Or any other ideas for having the same rendering on ImageMosaic as the GeoTiff store?

Here is a sample of the file if needed : https://www.dropbox.com/s/hz6j0m0ck2txncj/sample_jpeg_compression_internal_mask.tif?dl=1

Comment: Do you know if GeoServer can handle the internal mask at all with image mosaic? You can test it by using two adjacent tiffs in the mosaic and having a look at the seam.

Comment: Nope, GeoServer can not handle the internal mask at all with the default suggestedSPI of ImageMosaic. However, it works fine within a GeoTIFF store so I am wondering how it would be possible to use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer while looking at the ImageMosaic footprint [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_footprint/imagemosaic_footprint.html), and it was clearly explained in the 'Raster Masking' section:

> From 2.8.x version, GeoServer is able to support also Raster Masks.
>   Those masks can be **internal** or external

Thus, I simply needed to add a `footprints.properties` file containing

> footprint_source=raster

Then, when publishing the layer, setting `FootprintBehavior` to Transparent did the job !